# How does PHP SimpleXML get evaluated as an expression?

Tags: php, xml, casting, expression, simplexml

Consider this PHP code:

```
<?php
$xmlString = 
  '<'.'?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?'.'>' .
  '<rootEl>' .
      '<a attrA="valA">xxx</a>' .
      '<b attrB="valB"/>' .
      '<c>oink</c>' .
      '<d/>'.
      '<e>' .
          '<f>zzz</f>' .
      '</e>' .
  '</rootEl>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string( $xmlString );
foreach ( $xml->children() as $child ) {
    echo "\$CHILD [" . $child->getName() . "]: " . $child->asXML();
    echo "\n";
    $insideIf1 = false;
    if ($child) { $insideIf1 = true; }
    $insideIf2 = false;
    if (true == $child) { $insideIf2 = true; }
    $insideIf3 = false;
    if ((boolean)$child) { $insideIf3 = true; }

    echo "    - if(\$CHILD) return \"true\"; else return \"false\"; :                     " . (($insideIf1)?"true":"false")."\n";
    echo "    - if(true == \$CHILD) return \"true\"; else return \"false\"; :             " . (($insideIf2)?"true":"false")."\n";
    echo "    - if((boolean)\$CHILD) return \"true\"; else return \"false\"; :            " . (($insideIf3)?"true":"false")."\n";

    echo "    - ((\$CHILD)?\"true\":\"false\"):                                           " . (($child)?"true":"false")."\n";
    echo "    - ((true == \$CHILD)?\"true\":\"false\"):                                   " . ((true == $child)?"true":"false")."\n";
    echo "    - (((boolean)\$CHILD)?\"true\":\"false\"):                                  " . (((boolean)$child)?"true":"false")."\n";

    echo "\n";
}
```

As per PHP documentation (online, see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php):

> As described in the section about expressions, expression is evaluated
>   to its Boolean value. If expression evaluates to TRUE, PHP will
>   execute statement, and if it evaluates to FALSE - it'll ignore it.
>   More information about what values evaluate to FALSE can be found in
>   the 'Converting to boolean' section.

The "converting to boolean" section of this explanation states:

> Converting to boolean
>   When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>   ...omissis...
>
> ## SimpleXML objects created from empty tags

If you execute the code above, these are the results on my PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 (cli):

```
$CHILD [a]: <a attrA="valA">xxx</a>
- if($CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :                     true
- if(true == $CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :             true
- if((boolean)$CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :            true
- (($CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                           true
- ((true == $CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                   true
- (((boolean)$CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                  true

$CHILD [b]: <b attrB="valB"/>
- if($CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :                     true
- if(true == $CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :             false
- if((boolean)$CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :            true
- (($CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                           true
- ((true == $CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                   false
- (((boolean)$CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                  true

$CHILD [c]: <c>oink</c>
- if($CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :                     false
- if(true == $CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :             true
- if((boolean)$CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :            false
- (($CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                           false
- ((true == $CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                   true
- (((boolean)$CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                  false

$CHILD [d]: <d/>
- if($CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :                     false
- if(true == $CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :             false
- if((boolean)$CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :            false
- (($CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                           false
- ((true == $CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                   false
- (((boolean)$CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                  false

$CHILD [e]: <e><f>zzz</f></e>
- if($CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :                     true
- if(true == $CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :             false
- if((boolean)$CHILD) return "true"; else return "false"; :            true
- (($CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                           true
- ((true == $CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                   false
- (((boolean)$CHILD)?"true":"false"):                                  true
```

Children elements "b" and "d" ARE empty, therefore I was expecting "false", and "a", "c", "e" ARE NOT empty, so I was expecting "true".

As is comes out, that statement in PHP documentation is absolutely NOT true, and the behaviour doesn't even seem consistent: implicit or explicit casts to boolean don't behave the same way (see case of element "c"), and if the bare SimpleXML object is used as "if" conditional expression (both "if" and ternary operator), somehow that expression evaluates differently from a cast to boolean.

Does anyone have an idea of what's going on here?

Comment: Just filed this as BUG in PHP:
Bug #68507: SimpleXML objects casted to boolean inconsistently
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68507

Comment: Wouldn't be so sure. Have you checked structure of objects?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's discard some of your code.

```
foreach ( $xml->children() as $child ) {
    echo "\$CHILD [" . htmlspecialchars($child->getName()) . "]: " . htmlspecialchars($child->asXML());
    echo "\n";
    $insideIf1 = false;
    if ($child) { $insideIf1 = true; }
    $insideIf2 = false;
    if (true == $child) { $insideIf2 = true; }
    $insideIf3 = false;
    if ((boolean)$child) { $insideIf3 = true; }

    var_dump($child);
  //  echo intval($child)."\n";
    echo 'VALUE EVALUATES TO: '. $child."\n";
    echo "    - if(\$CHILD) return \"true\"; else return \"false\"; :                     " . (($insideIf1)?"true":"false")."\n";
    echo "    - if(true == \$CHILD) return \"true\"; else return \"false\"; :             " . (($insideIf2)?"true":"false")."\n";
    echo "    - if((boolean)\$CHILD) return \"true\"; else return \"false\"; :            " . (($insideIf3)?"true":"false")."\n";
// This part evaluated exactly same as above. So no need to make confusion
    echo "\n";
}
```

Next:

**First and third test**
Those are basically same. Object is considered true, if it has properties. So basically xml tag without attributes has no properties (just var_dump them).
Objects without properties (does not have attributes BUT NOTE THEY CAN have value - which is returned by iterator) considered false: `c`, `d`

**Second test**
This test on the other hand does not test object itself. But all values returned by it from casting to: int, bool and string.
One of those tests calls for `__toString` magic method. Which returns value. Then it evaluates to `true` (Elements `a` and `c`)

So its not random, but has special rules while considering it true or false.

Forgot to add

> Note: SimpleXML has made a rule of adding iterative properties to most methods. They cannot be viewed using var_dump() or anything else which can examine objects.

This "strange" behaviour is result of it implementing inerators.

Edit:
As you stated in comment what made you analyze this behaviour. I think that you should never chose to check SimpleXML objects on `if($obj)` basis.
Instead, use `SimpleXML::attributes()` or `strval` to do all checks. Then you're sure what you're checking.

Edit2:
**$xmlObject is considered true (is not empty) if it has Properties `OR` Chilren** (subnodes) (that works fine)
**To check if object has value you cast it to string.**

In this case, empty does not mean if it has value, only if it has children or properties.

Comment: Thanks Gacek. I don't think this is random behaviour, it has a pattern. But this behaviour is definitely NOT the one stated in PHP documentation, and can be cause of bugs in software based on PHP/SimpleXML, as the one I have just debugged in Magento (Admin Controller). Magento was relying on "if ($xmlElement)" to mean "if (''===((string)$xmlElement))". The issue seems to occur on PHP 5.5 and 5.4 but not on 5.3

Comment: Btw. I don't know what one would check using if($xmlElement). If it has children, attributes or value?

Comment: Well, accordingly to the PHP official documentation, that should tell you whether the element is empty or not...
See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php ("Converting to boolean", part related to SimpleXML) and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php:
As described in the section about expressions, expression is evaluated to its Boolean value. If expression evaluates to TRUE, PHP will execute statement, and if it evaluates to FALSE - it'll ignore it. More information about what values evaluate to FALSE can be found in the 'Converting to boolean' section.

Comment: I think this Edit2, should clear your doubts. PHP Docs are right. I think they were misread in this case. Or it's not clear what "empty object" means.

Comment: PHP Doc doesn't state "empty object", which I agree is confusing, it states "empty tag", which has a well-defined meaning in XML: either <x a="b"/> or <x></x> or <x/>, basically any xml tag with no content or children.

Comment: I submited bug to php to write a warning about it in documentation. I think behaviour is 100% correct and gives most of possibilities to check. I think whole answer explains every aspect of this behaviour now :) https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68540&thanks=4

Comment: Sorry Gacek, not really.
<b attrB="valB"/> - this one has properties (attribute, in XML terminology) but consistently evaluates to false, in boolean context.
Also, <c>oink</c> has a text child node, but explicit casting to boolean (e.g. "(boolean)$xml") evaluates to false, while implicit casting to boolean (e.g. "true == $xml") evaluates to true.
This is an inconsistency and a genuine bug, not just a documentation issue.

Comment: <b attrB="valB"/> is correct. You use == to compare. Which means it is cast to string, which is empty and evaluates to false. === would should give true only.
<c>oink</c> does not have child nodes. It has value only. For me it's most logical how it works now.

Comment: Strict comparison (===) wouldn't work as it checks the operand types along with the values and one of them is boolean and the other is SimpleXMLElement. 
With regards to conversion to string, I also disagree. The PHP documentation states, with regards to the "==" comparison operator 
(see http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php "Comparison with Various Types" section, with left operand boolean and any right operand) that is supposed to convert both sides to boolean, NOT string.

Comment: Also, a text node in "<c>oink</c>" is still a node, in fact that is included in $xml->children(), which returns child nodes, therefore "<c>oink</c>" HAS children nodes, they're just not elements.